# Browser default padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Browsers have default padding for HTML page.
For example my FF sets 8px margin of body element by default.
I can calculate default width padding for HTML page using

```
jQuery(window).width() - jQuery('body').innerWidth();
```

due to body element spans all available browser viewport width.
Also I have other browser which sets different values for width and height padding.
Could you propose way to calculate height padding?
Previous code will not work due to body inner height will return actual page content height and will not span all available height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need to calculate the padding? The padding is defined in an element's css setting for padding and margin.

You can get these easily in jQuery:

```
// Select the body element.
var bodyElement = $('body');

// Get the paddings
var widthPadding = bodyElement.css('padding-left') + bodyElement.css('padding-right');
var heightPadding = bodyElement.css('padding-top') + bodyElement.css('padding-bottom');

// Get the margins
var widthMargin = bodyElement.css('margin-left') + bodyElement.css('margin-right');
var heightMargin = bodyElement.css('margin-top') + bodyElement.css('margin-bottom');
```

You can remove the default user-agent (i.e. the browser's) settings by defining in your css file:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I was previously checked jQuery('body').css('margin') but it returned 0 for me. Your jQuery('body').css('margin-left') returns 8px. Working, thanks. Strange as for me...

Comment: The reason is that margin can be a value list, eg: `"10px 0 20px 30px"` (specifying top, right, bottom and left). If you just want one specific value, use the `margin-xxx` or `padding-xxx` where `xxx` is `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`.

Answer (score 3):

Bypass the problem and use a [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

With a good reset, you will not have to calculate these as they will be set by yourself.

Comment: I'm developing third party library and this will be viewed as undesirable side effect.

Comment: @Mykhaylo Adamovych - that's the kind of detail you should put in your question.